# Selenium WebDriver w/Java. trouble selecting items in a pop up window

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, popup

SwitchWindow, Frame, Alert, everything I can think of and after lots of searching. Nothing has worked so far.

When I click on an "edit" button, a new window pops up with a text box, special character selection, save and exit buttons. All I want to do is enter text in the box but for some reason webdriver can not find the element.

Here's some HTML. The 
        textarea name="specHeading" 
is what I'm trying to edit.

```
<script src="/js/componentlist.js" type="text/javascript">
<script src="/js/mrinformation.js" type="text/javascript">
<script src="/js/jquery.resources.js" type="text/javascript">
<script src="/js/validateresources.js" type="text/javascript">

<div class="ckmodal-next" style="top: 9px; left: 1281.5px;"></div>
<div class="ckmodal-prev" style="top: 9px; left: 261.5px;"></div>
<div class="ckmodal-close" style="top: -225px; left: 1239px;"></div>
<div class="ckmodal-background" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; position: fixed; top: 0px; left: 0px; background-color: rgb(51, 51, 51); opacity: 0.8; z-index: 10000000;"></div>
<div class="modal-container" style="opacity: 1; position: fixed; top: -212.5px; left: 321.5px; display: block; z-index: 10000001;">
    <form class="form">
       <div class="row">
          <div class="col24">
             <div class="box box-gray">
                <h2>
                   <div class="content">
                      <fieldset class="full">
                         <div class="form-field full">
                            <label>Heading:</label>
                            <textarea name="specHeading"></textarea>
                         </div>
                         <div class="form-field full">
                            <div class="form-field bottom full">
                      </fieldset>
                      <div class="clear"></div>
                   </div>
                </div>
             </div>
          </div>
       </form>
    </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

It looks like there's no windows to switch to, and it's not an iframe, nor an alert.  Here's what I think is the JavaScript from the modal.

```
<script src="/js/productheaders.js" type="text/javascript">
    ;(function($){
        var $currentEditHeader = null;

        function setupForm(e) {
            var $this = $(this),
            value = $this.siblings('span').html();

            $currentEditHeader = $this.parents('.product-header');
            $('#edit-header').ckmodal({
                onShow: function(){
                    $('textarea[name=specHeading]').val(value.replace(/<br\s*[\/]?>/g, '\n')).focus();
            }
        });
    }

function saveHeader(e) {
    var $this = $(this),
    value = $('textarea[name=specHeading]').last().val();

    if ( value == '' ) {
        var defaultValue = $currentEditHeader.attr('data-default-value');
        $currentEditHeader.children('span').text(defaultValue);
        $currentEditHeader.addClass('default');
    } else {
        $currentEditHeader.children('span').html(value.replace(/<[^>]*>?/g, '').replace(/\n/g, '<br>'));
        $currentEditHeader.removeClass('default');
    }
```

Comment: I updated your formatting and as I was doing so I found a lot of syntax errors and typos.  I did not correct these because that may be your issue.  Double check over all of your code (both html & JS) to make sure that isn't what's causing your issue.  However, if they are copy-paste issues then just please clean up your question a bit.

Comment: Sorry, this is not my code. I just copied this from a site that I'm testing. I'm a consultant for another company.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "popup" might be not a separate window/frame/alert, but part of your main page, which is just made visible.
You can treat it as such. Hard to tell with just this excerpt.

You might have to wait for it to be visible if there is some kind of animation involved.

Additionally, there are some issues inserting text in those text fields. The following worked for us in such cases:

1. Call `textFieldElement.clear()`
2. Then call `textFieldElement.sendKeys()`

Comment: I'll give this a shot as soon as I get back to my computer! Thanks!

Comment: Thank you! This worked. I did end up having to use the Actions class to send text to the text box, using clear and sendKeys was not working. for whatever reason, the textArea was not able to be found by selenium.